# Compare optimization algorithms with stop criteria

Tags: classification, optimization

I'm comparing Harmony Search and Genetic Algorithm for a specific finance case study. I set a early stopping criteria. If we don't have improvement in 1/5 of total iterations of algorithm, It will stop. I set two algorithms total iterations to 300 (60 for early stopping). My questions :

1. Should I repeat every algorithms for some times and average between resulted errors(I have classification problem for cost function)? If yes, how many time?
2. Should I disable early stopping for comparing algorithms and only set a specific total iterations for two algorithms? or It is true to active early stopping?